# Is it possible to add to cart with a radio input rather than a select?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2, ecommerce, plugin-digitalproducts

I'd like to add a digital product to the cart using a radio input but all the template examples I see use select. Is it possible to use a radio input?

**With Select (working):**

```
<select name="purchasableId">
  {% for digitalProduct in entry.fontProducts.all() %}
    <option value="{{digitalProduct.purchasableId}}">{{digitalProduct.slug}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

**With radio inputs (not working):**

```
{% for digitalProduct in entry.exampleProducts.all() %}
  <li>
    <div>
      <input 
        type="radio"
        name="product"
        value="{{digitalProduct.purchasableId}}" />
    </div>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` for your input needs to be `purchasableId`:

```
{% for digitalProduct in entry.exampleProducts.all() %}
  <li>
    <div>
      <input 
        type="radio"
        name="purchasableId"
        value="{{digitalProduct.purchasableId}}" />
    </div>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```